# If Spring creates a DAG of beans it got to create. What is the additional benfit of using @DependOn?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired, spring-ioc

Here, is a detailed post on how spring dependencies on one another can be resolved using `@DependsOn` --> [Controlling Bean Creation Order with @DependsOn Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-depends-on)

But some time in the past I have read that spring container creates a DAG of all the beans before it starts initiating or creating the beans. If this is the case, dependencies are automatically addressed using DAG mechanism. So is not @DependsOn redundant.

But if Spring framework is providing one such annotation explicitly, I assume it must carry some real importance. Could someone clarify if there's something I am missing?

Comment: That only applies to injection, sometimes you want to have a bean which needs to be created after another one. Like you have a datasource, sessionfactory and use FlyWay to manage the schema. You want flyway to run **before** hibernate initializes. Then you will need an `@DependsOn` to let hibernate wait on flyway to be available.

Comment: fine got it.. will remove this Q after a while.